# How to duplicate a standard Salesforce button?

Tags: salesforce

I have a `Case` object page layout with `Case Comments` and `Emails` related lists. I would like to duplicate the `New` button for the `Case Comments` and the `Send an Email` button for the `Emails`, which are both standard buttons.

By duplicate, I mean I would like to copy them and simply add them to the very top of the page where they could sit by the `Edit`, `Delete` and `Close Case` buttons.

Is this possible? If not, how do I approach triggering a new email, or a new Case Comment with a custom button?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't know what salesforce is, but you might want to check this out: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is possible. Just go to the Case object settings and create a new Custom Button:

- Label: new case (or what ever)
- Display Type: Detail Page Button
- Behavior: Execute JavaScript
- Content Source: Onclick JavScript

For the code area add the following commands:

- Select Field Type: $Action
- Insert Field: Your object

The code will be automatically inserted. Put it to the javascript window.open function like this:

```js
window.open("{!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase)}");
```

Noe just save it and insert the new button to your standard page layout.